# Do banks control ripple and how?

Tags: ripple, banks

I would like to know how banks are controlling ripple. What are the implications with regards to transaction fees? If I sell my ripple, what do I stand to lose in terms of bank charges?

Answer (score 1):

Banks don't control Ripple. Ripple is a corporation that is controlled by its stockholders. XRP is a cryptocurrency that trades on a public ledger. If you sell XRP on an exchange, you pay whatever the exchange charges, just like with bitcoin or Ethereum.